# Get pods last reboot from command line in OpenShift

Tags: openshift

I am running OpenShift 3.11.

I would like to get, from command line (*oc*), a list of all the last reboots occurred on my pods and of course the time when it happened.

Comment: Hi @Natrium, It's not possible to see the restart and its timestamp with the current podSpec. you can get the number of restart of the container inside the pod with the folllowing command ` oc get pod <POD>  -o jsonpath={'.status.containerStatuses[0].restartCount'}`